# I want to hide the parent div if child div is empty as Filter results empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular-filters

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in report.practices">
    <div >{{key}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="(severityIndex, severityName) in val">
    <div ng-if="filterResults.length" >
        <span >{{severityIndex}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="(practice, value) in val[severityIndex] | filter:searchText.value as filterResults">
      <span >{{practice}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am printing in the below format,

Category :
SubCategory :
Content :

In the above format I applies filter search for **Content** and applied the filter results length to **SubCategory**. So that If no **content** filtered then **Subcategory** hide successfully. Now also I want to hide the **Category(parent)**, if no **Subcategory** is filtered.

Please help me how could I achieve this ?